# Pandas Fill NaN Using based on Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

Let's assume we have a Pandas DataFrame as follows.

```
+------------+--------+-------+
|    Date    | Price  | Proxy |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 | NaN    |    10 |
| 2021-01-02 | NaN    |    20 |
| 2021-01-03 | NaN    |    30 |
| 2021-01-04 | NaN    |    24 |
| 2021-01-05 | 10     |    35 |
| 2021-01-06 | 11     |    45 |
| 2021-01-07 | 32     |    32 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

The above can be generated using the code below

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05',
                 '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07'],
        'Price': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 11, 32],
        'Proxy': [10, 20, 30, 24, 35, 45, 32]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

In case where `Price` is `NaN` i want to fill it using formula below.

[image: $$Price_{t}$$]

I am unable to figure out how to apply operation on column `Price` as it is getting updated, using a vectorised approach.

**Expected Output**

```
+------------+--------+-------+
|    Date    | Price  | Proxy |
+------------+--------+-------+
| 2021-01-01 |   0.17 |    10 |
| 2021-01-02 |   0.43 |    20 |
| 2021-01-03 |   1.15 |    30 |
| 2021-01-04 |   3.72 |    24 |
| 2021-01-05 |     10 |    35 |
| 2021-01-06 |     11 |    45 |
| 2021-01-07 |     32 |    32 |
+------------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Where does the 3.72 came from?

Comment: @DaniMesejo I believe it comes from 10 / ((24/35)+2)

Comment: @DaniMesejo that is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by `using a vectorised approach`?

Comment: @meti I mean I don't want to use loops.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this soulution using a for loop (which might not be the most efficient solution).

First, reverse the order of the DataFrame (in order to apply the for loop starting from the most recent values):

```
df = df.sort_values('Date', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then you can apply this for loop to replace the null values with the formula you indicated:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (index > 0) & (pd.isnull(row['Price'])):
        df.loc[index, 'Price'] = df.loc[index-1, 'Price'] / \
                                 ((df.loc[index, 'Proxy'] / df.loc[index-1, 'Proxy']) + 2)
```

Now if you can display the DataFrame in the original order with `df.round(2).sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)`, and the output is:

```
    Date        Price   Proxy
0   2021-01-01  0.17    10
1   2021-01-02  0.43    20
2   2021-01-03  1.15    30
3   2021-01-04  3.72    24
4   2021-01-05  10.00   35
5   2021-01-06  11.00   45
6   2021-01-07  32.00   32
```