# Python Data Frame - How can I evaluate/use a column being created on the fly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization, fillna

Suppose that I have a dataframe as follows:

```
+---------+-------+------------+
| Product | Price | Calculated |
+---------+-------+------------+
| A       |    10 | 10         |
| B       |    20 | NaN        |
| C       |    25 | NaN        |
| D       |    30 | NaN        |
+---------+-------+------------+
```

The above can be created using below code:

```
data = {'Product':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Price':[10, 20, 25, 30],
        'Calculated':[10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to update column `calculated` on the fly. For 2nd row the `calculated = Prv. calculated / Previous Price` i.e. `calculated` at row 2 is `10/10=1`

Now that we have value for row 2 `calculated` row 3 `calculated` would be `1/20` and so on and so forth.

**Expected Output**

```
+---------+-------+------------+
| Product | Price | Calculated |
+---------+-------+------------+
| A       |    10 |         10 |
| B       |    20 |          1 |
| C       |    25 |       0.05 |
| D       |    30 |      0.002 |
+---------+-------+------------+
```

The above can be achieved using loops but I don't want to use loops instead I need a vectorized approach to update column `Calculated`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: In the `calculated` column after the first `non-NaN` value are all the subsequent values `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at `cumprod` with a `shift`:

```
# also `df['Calculated'].iloc[0]` instead of `.ffill()`
df['Calculated'] = df['Calculated'].ffill()/df.Price.cumprod().shift(fill_value=1)
```

Output:

```
  Product  Price  Calculated
0       A     10      10.000
1       B     20       1.000
2       C     25       0.050
3       D     30       0.002
```

Comment: Thanks for this methodology I'll be able to solve the question below now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786224/pandas-fill-nan-using-based-on-conditions
I was stuck at above question now I can have a sense on how to solve such problems.